# how can I recover a modified file in linux

Tags: linux, vim

I had created a file `filedetails.cpp`. after editing the file, i got this error :

```
**memory full. unable to edit file**
```

Then I quit(`q`) and I re-open again to see the file empty.
but there are 4 more files creates :

```
filedetails.cpp~
filedetails.cpw~
filedetails.cpx~
filedetails.cpy~
filedetails.cpz~
```

I dont understand what has happened and how can I recover.

Comment: If you were using vim editor to edit the file then you can recover file with command "vim -r filename". For more detail, see [Vim Recovery Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html)

Comment: Why do you use the `c++`, `c` and `gcc` tags?

Comment: Learn to use version control.

Answer (score 0):

The files with the `~` ending are *backup files*. You can inspect them in Vim (or in the shell via `cat`), and their creation dates; if one of them is complete, recover by just copying it back to your original file (`cp filedetails.cpz~ filedetails.cpp` in the shell, or `:saveas filedetails.cpp` in Vim).